# Mailchimp - Delete all products

Tags: e-commerce, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to clean up old products from a mailchimp database using API v3.0.

Mailchimp's E-commerce [documentation](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/ecommerce/stores/products/) explains how to delete a single product using:

```
DELETE /ecommerce/stores/{store_id}/products/{product_id}
```

Is there a way to delete all products at once? I cannot do it manually since I have thousands of records to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to delete all products at once, so I wrote a NodeJS script to delete products in batches :

```js
// delete-script.js
const request = require('request')

const headers = { 'Authorization': 'Basic XXX-usX' }
const productsUri = 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/ecommerce/stores/XX/products'

const erasePage = request.bind(this, {
  uri: `${productsUri}?count=1000`,
  method: "GET",
  headers
}, (err, res, body) => {
  const products = JSON.parse(body).products
  const length = products.length

  if (length === 0) return

  let resolvedDeletions = 0

  products.forEach(({ id }) => {
    request({
      uri: `${productsUri}/${id}`,
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers
    }, err => {
      if (err) return console.error(err)

      console.log('deleted ', id)

      if (++resolvedDeletions === length) erasePage()
    })
  })
})

erasePage()
```

Simply `npm install request` then execute script with `node delete-script.js`

Comment: Nice, you could also do it in a batch operation, doing this this way could cause your API key to exceed the limit of 10 simultaneos request.